# My dualboot windows 8.1 ubuntu is not working

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I'm trying for 2 weeks to install ubuntu on dual boot with my brand new G551 asus windows 8.1 and I don't succeed.

I succeeded to install Ubuntu but I can't boot to there, I've no grub who shows up and tried different solutions from the forums but it's still not working..

Here is my boot info. If you can help me it would be so great!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10690789/

I've this when I'm trying boot repair

The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

I can't figure out how to do it.. How can I boot on UEFI mode ? Because I don't see the options in the boot menu

---

To be more precise, I deactivated fastboot and gone into UEFI Boot system. There I enabled CSM mode and Installed ubuntu with LIVE CD (I had to do like this otherwise LIVECD wasn't recognize). I installed ubuntu with "install ubuntu beside windows" without changing anything.

Then I rebooted the system, and was unable to see ubuntu. I know there is ubuntu installed, because I saw it on the partitions, but can't access in the bios to ubuntu or no grub is showing up... Do you know how to do it ?

I see in different posts another skin for UEFI bios. But I can't reach it. I've the old skin of the bios, and only some few options to boot. I tried escape and f2 at the start but still the same BIOS.

Does someone know How I can reach this UEFI bios ?

Comment: In my case I have to enable/disable Secure Boot/Legacy Mode in order to boot Windows 8/Ubuntu :) A bit clumsy, but fortunately I usually never boot to Windows 8.

Comment: UEFI and Legacy CSM/BIOS boot modes are not compatible. You actually should be able to dual boot, but have to go into UEFI and turn on UEFI to boot Windows and then go into UEFI and turn off UEFI or turn on BIOS/CSM mode to boot Ubuntu. Better to have Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Boot-Repair should convert install to UEFI if you boot it in UEIF mode. YOu may have to turn on UEFI mode settings in UEFI first.

Comment: Well I too have faced this problem on my Lenovo g510 windows 8.1. But fortunately, this problem has already been faced by lot of other users. Therefore after doing some googling about this, I have managed to fix this. Hope that following references will help you. Tip : use 2gb or 4gb (i had problem with 8gb) flash drive to make Live USB/DVD http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: There is a very detailed answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: I followed all this tutorials, and I didn't figured out how to do it. I did booting in uefi, fastboot deactivaiton, secureboot disable, enabled CRM qnd activate after installing. It's just not the solution for my problem. I don't know why. it's getting me crazy...

Comment: anyone knows why I'm not booting on UEFI mode ? I did all the steps recommended but still ...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem two weeks ago. I didn't have a pre-installed Win8.1. I started out with a clean HDD.

If you do have Win8 pre-installed, [deactivate fast boot](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) and [secure boot](http://itsfoss.com/disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-8/).

If that doesn't help, try with the utility tool boot-repair from a LiveUSB.

For my problem in particular, after using boot-repair, my win8 didn't appear afterwards in GRUB, so I also did a

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This I will try, I did not try :) thx :)

Comment: @DaschPyth Did you fix it?

Comment: It worked for a period, but then I upgraded to Win10 and I broke things again. Ended up formatting the whole HDD to GPT (UEFI format) and reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 1):

In the BIOS, select UEFI instead of legacy mode as the boot mode. That might do it.

1. Boot into the BIOS window
2. Select Boot.
3. In the Boot, boot mode, select UEFI
4. Save and Exit

This should work

Hope you have already deactivated fast-boot and secure-boot

Comment: The problem is that I don't have UEFI... I've only FASTBOOT and CSM mode. So I tried to add a boot option where I selected EFI/efi-64.boot something like this but still, I can't access it... I did deactivate fast boot and secure boot

Answer (score 0):

hold left shift key while booting.it will show the grub menu.

Comment: I already did. I'm still block to install it. I think the problem is to boot into the UEFI bios because I can't reach it... PLEASE HELP ME !!! it has been 1 month and I still can't boot into Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to disable anything. I had this problem yesterday, and was able to fix it, now I can choose which OS I want to boot to. Below are the step.

You can boot to Linux as a live user or if you can from your installed Linux, either way, try to start Linux. Make sure you are connected to the internet.

Then type these commands one by one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then when you see a dialog appear, select "Recommended Repair". Then just follow the wizard. NOTE: you might or might not receive an error something like this "Secure Boot Error" which I did receive, don't worry, just keep proceeding as normal, no need to do anything about it. Then by the end you will see a success dialog telling you to write down a link, just read that dialog carefully. Then don't forget to write down the command at the end of that dialog or you can take a picture of it with your phone like I did. Just follow the instruction provided in the dialog. when you have done everything like I suggest. You will see this screen every time you boot your computer.

:) Dont mind the text on the image, I was just showing off my new dual OSs to my friends :). Hope this helps you
[image]

Comment: I can't do a boot-repair because that I'm launching the USB LIve session in Legacy mode. I can't figure out to boot onto UEFI mode...

Comment: I didnt have to disable anything nor did I boot in legacy mode. I just told the system to boot from an usb, and just installed my ubuntu

Comment: Yes you're lucky. Because I'm still stuck ! If I use boot-repair. I've to boot into UEFI MODE to do it. But I don't manage to boot the USB in UEFI MODE. Because I think I don't have the UEFI Bios. I've the classical one with few options as I explain before.

Comment: Just re-enable everything, set everything back to factory default settings. UEFI is the new "BIOS", legacy mode is like the traditional BIOS. To boot from a USB,  I don't want boot to my Windows at the moment to show you the exact steps to boot from a USB since I have an SSD for LInux, it does everything much much faster, so just follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsBo8yikz7U to boot from a USB

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS X-series with Win 8.1 and I had to turn off fast boot (there was no secure boot or legacy option in my UEFI).

You can do this most easily via recovery options in Windows. In other words, with my ASUS, I could only access UEFI settings from within Windows (Windows will restart into UEFI). After re-reading your question, I suspect that you haven't corrected your UEFI settings before trying to install Ubuntu.

Then made sure grub was installed on sda (the primary HDD) and not in any sub partitions (ie, sda1, sda2, etc.)

I use Kubuntu, so there is no "Install with Windows" option during install, but setting up the proper partitions is fairly simple.

Here's a short video:

https://youtu.be/wo2k8pO4O_Y